# Apple Pay :Is it possible to get name on card which is selected by user from apple pay tray?

Tags: ios, applepay

I am working on Integrating Apple Pay in my app. I need following details to post to api :
1. Name on the card, 
2. last 4 four digits,
3. type of card (VISA, AMEX etc)

Is there a way to retrieve those from the card selected by user in Apple Pay tray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the name on the card via ApplePay. This is one of the reasons why a lot of merchants have resisted it. But Apple did this to protect users' privacy: you should be able to buy something without telling someone your name. If someone doesn't know your name then how can they identity fraud you?

If you want the customer's name, *ask them*, or have employees check their ID and require that the name be entered into the system. If you can't be asked to bother asking the customer to identify themselves, then, since the customer has not voluntarily given you their name, why do you deserve to have it?

Comment: Ya seems like we don't deserver to have it and the only way to get it is to ask customers.

Comment: I don't agree with this statement.  Your presuming it's in a situation in a physical store.  For online web transactions where the name is coming through on the order anyway, why is the customer's name restricted?  It now doesn't appear in our Stripe dashboard and it's frustrating for reporting.  We have the name from their order so this is achieving nothing apart from wasting our time.